# Issue testing Accept request header in Spring MockMvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit, mocking

I am trying to unit test SpringBoot Controller. Objective is to test that we return `406 Not Acceptable` when request header contains `Accept` as anything other than `application/json`. But I find its not working with `MockMvc`. I am getting 200 OK instead of 406. Any ideas please! Of course, service returns 406 as expected when I test using Postman or any rest client.

```
@Test
public void shouldRejectIfInvalidAcceptHeaderIsPassed() throws Exception {

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("Accept","application/xml");
    httpHeaders.add("Authorization", "some jwt token");

    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/sample/test")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .headers(httpHeaders)
            .content(toJson("")))
            .andExpect(status().isNotAcceptable());

    // Then
    verify(mockSampleService).getSampleOutput();
}
```

And my controller looks like,

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping(PATH_PREFIX)
public class SampleController {

    public static final String PATH_PREFIX = “/sample”;

    private final SampleService sampleService;

    @Autowired
    public SampleController(SampleService sampleService) {
        sampleService = sampleService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = “/test”, method = RequestMethod.POST))
    public SampleResponse createSession() {
        return sampleService.getSampleOutput();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the accept() method instead, e.g.

```
    mvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders
        .get("/some/test/url")
        .content(...)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .andExpect(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh! I have identified and fixed the issue. In the controller we need to have, `@RequestMapping(headers="Accept=application/json")`. Else MockMvc is not able to identify the expected format.

Comment: You could have added:
@RequestMapping(PATH_PREFIX, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")